# Vector.class doesn't exist in Mahout-core 0.7 -cdh4.2.1 jar, not able to run SimpleKMeansClustering Example

Tags: hadoop, cluster-analysis, mahout, k-means

Hi i'm new to Mahout so was to trying to run the [SimpleKMeansClustering](https://github.com/tdunning/MiA/blob/master/src/main/java/mia/clustering/ch07/SimpleKMeansClustering.java) from Github.
I dowloaded the Mahout-core jar from [Cloudera Repository](https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/public/org/apache/mahout/mahout-core/0.7-cdh4.2.1-SNAPSHOT/mahout-core-0.7-cdh4.2.1-20130329.164646-3.jar).

Now when i'm trying to compile my code in eclipse, i cannot find the Vector.Class in org.apche.mahout.math

Please can you let me know where i can find the Vector.class or how to run a clustering example on my own.

**Note:** I'm using Hadoop Chd4.2.1 and the mahout example for Syntheticcontrol data works fine so its just i'm looking for a custom code for my own data to cluster, so that i can run that in mahout.

Please help we are in a deadline to showcase some capability of Hadoop in Machine Learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your classpath is incomplete.

You are missing the mahout-math jar.

Probably here:

```
/usr/lib/mahout/mahout-math-0.7.jar
```

That is the path on my system.

Comment: Thanks anony i got that jar and the vector.class, but still i'm facing some error in this part of code.                         "for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {      
   Vector vec = vectors.get(i);      
   Cluster cluster = new Cluster(vec, i, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());      
   writer.append(new Text(cluster.getIdentifier()), cluster);    
  }    
  writer.close();        
  
  
  KMeansDriver.run(conf, new Path("testdata/points"), new Path("testdata/clusters"),"

Comment: i'm geeting an error Cannot instantiate the the type cluster in the below snipet of code. Can anyone help me with this.            Cluster cluster = new Cluster(vec, i, new EuclideanDistanceMeasure());

Comment: I don't use k-means in mahout. I don't have interesting data that is too large for my computer, and ELKI is much faster on a single host than Mahout. Either way, try `new DistanceMeasureCluster`

Answer (score 0):

It does exist. This suggets you haven't set up your project correctly in Eclipse. It's hard to say how without any detail. But this is nothing to do with CDH or Mahout.